# Jersey Client POST is returning a un-formatted XML Response

Tags: java, xml, rest, xml-parsing, jersey-client

I'm new to Jersey and have been trying to POST from a input XML file . Posting is successful and i do get a XML Response back but not in a formatted way .

Jersey Client :

```
  ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
            Client client = Client.create(config);
            WebResource service = client.resource("mybaseURI");
            client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("username","password"));
            ClientResponse response = service.type("application/xml")
                                     .accept("application/xml")
                                     .header("Headername", "Value")
                                     .post(ClientResponse.class,new File("C:\\RequestXML.xml"));
            System.out.println(response);
```

How can i get a well formatted XML Response from Jersey .

XML Response :

```
<result class="string">&lt;execution-results&gt;
  &lt;result identifier=&quot;result&quot;&gt;
    &lt;com.pnmac.sse.cash.Result&gt;
      &lt;Name&gt;true&lt;/Name&gt;
      &lt;Place&gt;false&lt;/Place&gt;
      &lt;Age&gt;&lt;/Age&gt;
      &lt;DOB&gt;Posting Instruction&lt;/DOB&gt;
      &lt;Sex&gt;
```

Comment: Could you post method signature along with Produces and Consumes

Comment: @RajavelD Both my Consumes and Produces have MediaType as Application_XML . But the response what i'm getting is a raw XML data . But i want the response to be in proper XML format .

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
```

Make sure you mention the mediaType as Application_xml